# How to deploy Kubernetes with Docker locally?

Tags: deployment, docker, kubernetes

Can Kubernetes be deployed with Docker locally now?

I see the tutorial of deploying Kubernetes with docker on the Kubernetes official website has been removed.In the [Kubernetes' download link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/binary_release/), Docker is no longer one of providers. And I have tried to deploy Kubernetes with following commands which are similar to the old official tutorial.

```
docker run -d \
--net=host \
gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9 \
/usr/local/bin/etcd \
    --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 \
    --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 \
    --data-dir=/var/etcd/data

docker run -d \
--net=host \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1  \
/hyperkube kubelet \
    --api_servers=http://localhost:8080 \
    --v=2 \
    --address=0.0.0.0 \
    --enable_server \
    --hostname_override=127.0.0.1 \
    --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests

docker run -d \
--net=host \
--privileged \
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1  \
/hyperkube proxy \
    --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 \
    --v=2
```

The result is that only etcd, kubelet and proxy are created. And I can not connect Kubernetes server with kubectl. The results of docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c21652ceae44        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1   "/hyperkube proxy --m"   28 seconds ago       Up 27 seconds                           sleepy_bardeen
ee4568ed948c        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.1   "/hyperkube kubelet -"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       elegant_hugle
533c459ec7d4        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9         "/usr/local/bin/etcd "   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       condescending_bhabha
```

Comment: Have you looked at [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube)?

Comment: Thank you! I have tried it. But I run Ubuntu VM on the Windows, thus I can not create virtual machine in Ubuntu. So I can not start local Kubernetes cluster. I will try it on other machines later.

Comment: I have figured it out by using minikube of Windows version. It starts kubernetes server in the minikube VM, and I can interact with the server with kubernetes UI or kubectl in the minikubeVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kubernetes is an orchestration(scheduling) system for docker container and don't run inside docker, because k8ts need docker daemon to schedule and orchestrate container.

k8ts need physical(bare metal or other) or virtual machine to run.
for run kubernetes locally you can use [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube).